# Micrometer Counter vs DistributionSummary

Tags: java, prometheus, monitoring, metrics, micrometer

Using summary for request size I would track

- total requests
- total total request size
- biggest request size

I can do it like this

```
meterRegistry.summary("request.size", <tag for url>).record(<size>);
```

However I can achieve the same using counters and a gauge for the biggest size

```
meterRegistry.counter("request.size.total", <tag for url>).increment(<size>);
meterRegistry.counter("request.size.count", <tag for url>).increment();
meterRegistry.gauge("request.size.max", <tag for url>).set(<new value if needed>);
// and the gauge value will be stored in atomic variable
```

Question is, is there any benefit of summary over the longer solution except for being shorter?

Answer (score 1):

Using `DistributionSummary` means:

- writing and maintaining less code
- using Micrometer's naming conventions
- decay values over time (see: `distributionStatisticExpiry` and `distributionStatisticBufferLength`)
- you can have [histograms and percentiles](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_histograms_and_percentiles)
- you can define SLOs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jonatan Ivanov's answer.

Using counter with `tag = <request size>` means a ***new*** metric will be created for every request size. Which means you might end up with a huge amount of counters.

If you think that the distinguishing tag is something with fewer possible values and not too many counter metrics will be created, you can still use counter and make all of the aggregations the summary provides. (except quantiles).

I would use a counter if I am interested in for example the number of requests with size 450, this is not possible with the summary.

**TLDR**:

*Use summary if you are interested only in the total count and average size*

*Use a counter if the size variance isn't too big and you are interested in the exact count for a given size.*

Comment: But if you use `counter with tag = <request size> means a new metric will be created for every request size` you will potentially create a lot of meters due to high cardinality and probably have OOM.